Difference between $\mathbb R$-Cartier and $\mathbb R$-Cartier $\mathbb R$-divisors?
I am reading books (such as "Foundations of the minimal model program" by Fujino) in which appear the notion of $\mathbb R$-Cartier divisors, $\mathbb R$-divisors and $\mathbb R$-Cartier $\mathbb R$-divisors. We define notions of positivity (nefness for example) for $\mathbb R$-Cartier divisors, like in Lazarsfeld's book, so for a finite sum of Cartier divisors with real coefficients.
But then we talk about nefness for an $\mathbb R$-Cartier $\mathbb R$-divisor, which I understand to be a finite linear combinations of Cartier divisors, which can also be written as a finite linear combination of Weil divisors.
So what exactly is an $\mathbb R$-Cartier $\mathbb R$-divisor ? Is it enough to define positivity for $\mathbb R$-Cartier divisors instead of $\mathbb R$
-Cartier $\mathbb R$-divisors ?
